# Tools for SVN Merging

Tags: svn, merge

SVN merging is very time consuming (especially on large code bases) and error prone. Eclipse and Netbeans plugins don't serve me very well. At the moment I'm using a combination of manual "svn merge" and the graphical diff [Meld](http://meld.sourceforge.net/). Are there better alternatives (non-win32)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually there are reports of people using git-svn or hg-svn bridges to download a tree, preform a merge, then upload the merge. Doesn't solve the messiness part but the increased speed of the merge makes it less tedious.

Answer (score 11):

Meld is arguably one of the best and one of the most used tools for non-win32. On Windows or with Wine [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) wins hands down. Some alternatives for Linux:

- [Kompare](http://www.caffeinated.me.uk/kompare/)
- [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/)
- [DirDiff](http://freshmeat.net/projects/dirdiff/)

P.S. Actually on Windows the TortoiseSVN merge tool gives great results too :)

Comment: Unfortunately WinMerge does not support three-way merges.

Comment: @IgorBrejc because of this I use p4 when I'm on win http://www.perforce.com/product/components/perforce_visual_merge_and_diff_tools

Comment: KDiff3 runs on Windows, supports 3-way merge and is the most competent free merge tool out there.

Answer (score 11):

I have recently started using the new [Beyond Compare 3](http://scootersoftware.com) (for Windows and Linux). It seems to consistently make better automated merge decisions then TortoiseSVN or KDiff3. Particularly on whitespace, I believe this is due to BC3s better file type configuration.

I also think its merge interface is cleaner and easier to understand then KDiff.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out how to use SvnMerge, which is a Python script(s), and had quite a lot of success with it.  You can google for the instructions I put on my blog, or drop me a line and I'll post the vanity link.

Answer (score 2):

I really like Sourcegear Diffmerge.  http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/

Answer (score 1):

We have always used TortoiseSVN on my work.   Never had any problem with the merge so I can also recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [svnmerge](http://www.orcaware.com/svn/wiki/Svnmerge.py) and it helps a lot. It's a command line utility, so it may not be the best tool for everyone, but it's good for me.

Answer (score 0):

Which platform are you running on? On Windows I use **TortoiseSVN** to carry out most diffs and merges pretty easily. Only some of the more complicated strands of diffs are performed with UltraCompare.

Answer (score 0):

Best tool I've currently found for Linux is submerge from subcommander package. [Here](http://lifeinide.com/post/2011-08-06-edit-conflicts-in-eclipse-using-submerge/) is how to use this and integrate with eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I have created open source console tool to automate merging process. I think it can helpful for other peoples: [Merger](https://merger.codeplex.com/)
It can:
 - Switch subfolders in the folder to the new branch
 - Calculate difficulty of the future merge (number of commits/changed files/ commits to the same files, by project)
 - Merge revision by revision in auto mode, until no conflicts
 - Bulk merge of the groups of projects. 
In theory it should be able to work with mono.